# Binding textProperty to Expression

Tags: javafx, binding

Sorry if the question is looks pretty simple  but I'm little bit confused with Java bindings.

I need to bind textProperty  of the label   to the  SimpleIntegerProperty of the object but as a result of the condition check.

SimpleIntegerProperty can be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6     and depending on the value there's String values assigned to textProperty.

Like:

```
SimpleIntegerProperty is 0  ->  textProperty   displays "State 0"
SimpleIntegerProperty is 1  ->  textProperty   displays "State 1"
SimpleIntegerProperty is 2  ->  textProperty   displays "State 2"
```

etc...

I tried to do it with Bindings.createStringBinding  but it does not allow to use "if" statements inside it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure `createStringBinding` allows to use `if` or similar constructs. You just need to wrap it inside `{}` brackets and use `return`, in case you're using lambda expressions:

```
IntegerProperty property = ...
StringProperty target = ...
target.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    switch (property.get()) {
        case 0:
            return "State 0";
        case 1:
            return "State 1";
        case 2:
            return "State 2";
        case 3:
            return "State 3";
        case 4:
            return "State 4";
        case 5:
            return "State 5";
        case 6:
            return "State 6";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}, property));
```

or in case the pattern is always `"State "+value`

```
IntegerProperty property = ...
StringProperty target = ...
target.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    int value = property.get();
    return (value >= 0 && value <= 6) ? "State "+value : "";
}, property));
```

Comment: Thanks fabian! that is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IntegerBinding.asString(String format)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpressionBase.html#asString-java.lang.String-) for this:

```
IntegerProperty value = ... ;
Label label = new Label();
label.textProperty().bind(value.asString("State %d"));
```

Comment: James_D  thank you too for providing your approach     but my strings values are different words so I need to provide  particular word on particular number. I used in example to describe the problem.   Thanks a lot.